# Whenever I have a function which gets called on an event, it gets called on the event, unless it has arguments, in which it gets called immediately

Tags: python

I have a function which I have made, to shorten and simplify my code, for my chess game I'm making in Python. There is an issue though. The old function which I used, did not need any arguments, and activated when it was called, on an event. I had to copy and paste this function for every piece, which there are 32 of.

```
def darkPawn7Click(self):
    print("dark pawn 7 has been clicked")
```

I call this with the below;

```
pieceDarkPawn7.mouseReleaseEvent = darkPawn7Click
```

I then made a better set of functions which work around taking arguments and then using if statements to determine where the piece can move. I have not implemented this in the original function.

```
def showAvailMoves(pieceType, gridX, gridY, side):
    if pieceType == "pawn":
        if side == "light":
            if gridY == 6:
                availMoves = [gridY - 1, gridY - 2]
                return availMoves
            else:
                availMoves = [gridY - 1]
                return availMoves
        if side == "dark":
            if gridY == 1:
                availMoves = [gridY + 1, gridY + 2]
                return availMoves
            else:
                availMoves = [gridY - 1]
                return availMoves

def pieceClick(pieceType, gridX, gridY, side):
    print("piece Clicked")
    print(side + " " + pieceType + " at " + str(gridX) + " " + str(gridY))
    availMoves = showAvailMoves(pieceType, gridX, gridY, side)
    print(availMoves)
```

I call it with the below;

```
pieceDarkPawn8.mouseReleaseEvent = pieceClick("pawn", 7, 1, "dark")
```

For some reason, when I run the program with;

```
python .\chess.py
```

The function runs immediately, even though I haven't clicked on the said piece yet. This does not occur with the old function. It is to be said though that everything is being outputted correctly. Just to make sure, I tried calling the other function with;

```
pieceDarkPawn8.mouseReleaseEvent = darkPawn7Click("test")
```

It also gets run immediately. I'm starting to suspect that my code isn't at fault (however bad it is), but that there is a bug in Python itself. Doubt so though.

How would I go around fixing this?

Full code [here](https://github.com/Parmjot-Singh/chess).

Comment: *Obviously* there is no bug in python. When you write `something(...)` you call a function, that is what happens on the right side of your assignment. Instead you should have something like `pieceDarkPawn8.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda:  pieceClick("pawn", 7, 1, "dark")`

Comment: @luk2302 I tried adding lambda like you said, but now when I click the piece, nothing happens. It doesn't activate immediately though, which is a plus. Am I missing something?
No idea why I wrote there is a bug with Python.